# React jest and MSAL getting BrowserAuthError : crypto

Tags: java, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, package.json

I'm trying to test a few components that are using MSAL for authentication.

Thus far, I have a simple test, which test if my component can render, as follows:

```
// <MsalInstanceSnippet>
const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication({
  auth: {
    clientId: config.appId,
    redirectUri: config.redirectUri
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage',
    storeAuthStateInCookie: true
  }
});
```

When I run the test, I'm getting the following error:

```
 BrowserAuthError: crypto_nonexistent: The crypto object or function is not available. Detail:Browser crypto or msCrypto object not available.

      10 |
      11 | // <MsalInstanceSnippet>
    > 12 | const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication({
         |                      ^
      13 |   auth: {
      14 |     clientId: config.appId,
      15 |     redirectUri: config.redirectUri

      at BrowserAuthError.AuthError [as constructor] (node_modules/@azure/msal-common/dist/error/AuthError.js:27:24)
      at new BrowserAuthError (node_modules/@azure/msal-browser/src/error/BrowserAuthError.ts:152:9)
      at Function.Object.<anonymous>.BrowserAuthError.createCryptoNotAvailableError (node_modules/@azure/msal-browser/src/error/BrowserAuthError.ts:172:16)
      at new BrowserCrypto (node_modules/@azure/msal-browser/src/crypto/BrowserCrypto.ts:31:36)
      at new CryptoOps (node_modules/@azure/msal-browser/src/crypto/CryptoOps.ts:45:30)
      at PublicClientApplication.ClientApplication (node_modules/@azure/msal-browser/src/app/ClientApplication.ts:108:58)
      at new PublicClientApplication (node_modules/@azure/msal-browser/src/app/PublicClientApplication.ts:49:9)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.test.tsx:12:22)
```

I'm unsure what the above means, but as far as I can understand, this error is occurring because the session is not authenticated.

My question can therefore be divided into the following:

What does this error mean?
How can I solve this error? (Can we bypass MSAL by any chance for testing purposes?)

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `crypto` to your Jest config in `jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    // ...
    globals: {
        // ...
        crypto: require("crypto")
    }
};
```

Comment: It's a working solution even though eslint complains about not expecting require.

Answer (score 0):

For eslint issue
try this way

```
import crypto from 'crypto';

module.exports = {
    // ...
    globals: {
        // ...
        crypto,
    }
};
```

Comment: I am still getting error, even after implementing your above solution. added 'import crypto from 'crypto';
module.exports = {
 roots: ['<rootDir>/src'],
 transform: {
  '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
 },
 testRegex: '(/test/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$',
 moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
 globals: {
  crypto: crypto,
 },
};
'

Comment: @Gajen Please try this. maybe a help
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73244401/10564312

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding crypto to my jest.config.js, but it didn't work. Then I tried adding it package.json. It was also pointless giving this error.

```
Out of the box, Create React App only supports overriding these Jest options:

  • clearMocks
  • collectCoverageFrom
  • coveragePathIgnorePatterns
  • coverageReporters
  • coverageThreshold
  • displayName
  • extraGlobals
  • globalSetup
  • globalTeardown
  • moduleNameMapper
  • resetMocks
  • resetModules
  • restoreMocks
  • snapshotSerializers
  • testMatch
  • transform
  • transformIgnorePatterns
  • watchPathIgnorePatterns.

These options in your package.json Jest configuration are not currently supported by Create React App:
```

In my case, I have a custom hook that has a dependency with `msalInstance`

I can prevent the above error by mocking my hook as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69138146/10564312)

But still, this wasn't a good solution because if I have many hooks like this. So what I did was mock `msalInstance` in `setupTests.ts` file

```
jest.mock('./msal-instance', () => ({
  getActiveAccount: () => ({}),
  acquireTokenSilent: () => Promise.resolve({ accessToken: '' }),
}));
```

This is my `msal-instance.ts`

```
import {
  PublicClientApplication,
  EventType,
  EventMessage,
  AuthenticationResult,
} from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { msalConfig } from './authConfig';

const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

// Account selection logic is app dependent. Adjust as needed for different use cases.
const accounts = msalInstance.getAllAccounts();
if (accounts.length > 0) {
  msalInstance.setActiveAccount(accounts[0]);
}

msalInstance.addEventCallback((event: EventMessage) => {
  if (event.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_SUCCESS && event.payload) {
    const payload = event.payload as AuthenticationResult;
    const { account } = payload;
    msalInstance.setActiveAccount(account);
  }
});

export default msalInstance;
```

Comment: what to write in msal-instance file which you have mentoned in this line.. jest.mock('./msal-instance', () => ({

Comment: That file exports the `msal-instance`.

`const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);`

Answer (score 0):

For react version 17.x.x you can install "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17" package and after that you can create a src/setupTests.js file. You can add all your environment variables and other configurations to this file as follows:

```
//This is for the issue above
const nodeCrypto = require("crypto");
window.crypto = {
  getRandomValues: function (buffer) {
    return nodeCrypto.randomFillSync(buffer);
  },
};

//It is also possible to add ENV variables
window.ENV = {
  ApiURL: {
    lessonsUrl: "https://myApiURL.com/APIendpoint",
  }
  CloudUiUrl: "localhost:3000",
};
```

When you run your tests @wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17 will take the settings in this file automatically.