# Adding to globals in package.json jest config

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, azure-active-directory

I recently started using azure active directory in my create-react-app application and am running into this error when I try to run tests.

```
    BrowserAuthError: crypto_nonexistent: The crypto object or function is not available. Detail:Browser crypto or msCrypto object not available.

      25 | import { NavigationProvider } from './contexts/index';
      26 |
    > 27 | export const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
```

I found [React jest and MSAL getting BrowserAuthError : crypto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69629094/react-jest-and-msal-getting-browserautherror-crypto) which seems to be my exact issue, however my jest config is in my package.json and appears like this:

```
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx}",
      "!src/**/*.{config,stories}.js",
      "!src/**/index.js"
    ],
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "branches": 80,
        "functions": 80,
        "lines": 80,
        "statements": 80
      }
    }
  },
```

After reading some documentation I am still having a hard time figuring out how to add `crypto` to my jest config when it is in my package.json. I also tried to migrate my jest config over to a standalone `jest.config.js` and switched my test script to `react-scripts test -- --config jest.config.js` but wasn't able to get it to work.

What would be the best way to solve this issue? I'm assuming it's an easy fix but I just haven't been able to figure out the correct syntax for either version of the config. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

jest automatically looks for a `src/setupTests.js` file that is automatically executed before running your tests. this means that you can add `global.crypto = require('crypto');` to the `setupTests.js` file and it will do the same job as adding the globals section to the `jest.config.js`.